# How to insert an image into docs.google.com using Selenium?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, automation

i just strarted researching into selenium
i want to insert an image into docs.google.com
i ran my script but it didn't click to button "Choose an image to upload".. Please, help me. My code is below

```
__author__ = 'sdn'
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    import unittest

    class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            self.driver.get("https://docs.google.com")
        def test_Login(self):
            driver = self.driver
            email = "username"
            passwd = "userpassword"
            emailElement = driver.find_element_by_id("Email")
            passwdElement = driver.find_element_by_id("Passwd")
            emailElement.clear()
            emailElement.send_keys(email)
            passwdElement.clear()
            passwdElement.send_keys((passwd))
            logInElement = driver.find_element_by_id("signIn")
            logInElement.click()
            addElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#docs-homescreen-add"))
            addElement.click()
            insert = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id("docs-insert-menu"))
            insert.click()
            ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-b-c d-u d-u-F").click()
            ActionChains(driver).send_keys("/home/sdn/Downloads/image.jpg").send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```